# Why $ for jquery doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I used the following to enqueue jquery plugins:

```
<?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'custom functions',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',
            array('jquery'),
            '1',
            true
        );
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'dotdotdot & lightbox',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js',
            array('jquery'),
            '1',
            true
        );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

And I don't know it it's related but jquery only responds to calling `jquery(...` and not `$(...`. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use closure for your scripts:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // do something...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It is safe way to use jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery supplied with WordPress is in noConflict mode to avoid issues with other libraries that may use the `$` as their object reference.

See [wp_enqueue_script: jQuery noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) for more info.