# wp_enqueue_script() not working at all

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to enqueue JavaScript files using wp_enqueue_script(), but it isn't working at all. Here is my code:

```
function load_css_js() {
    wp_enqueue_style('gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/gdgt-base.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('gdgt-icon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/css/gdgt.css', true);
    wp_register_script('gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gdgt-base.js', array( 'jquery' ) , true);
    wp_enqueue_script('gdgt-base');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_js');
```

However, when I deregister the default WP Javasciprt and register jquery from somewhere else, it works. What may cause this problem? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13):

[`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) accepts many parameters and it's very important to use them in correct order otherwise these functions will fail.

Here are complete set of parameters for each function.

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

In your `wp_enqueue_style` you define `$handle`, `$src` correctly but `$deps` to `true` which is not correct. Same goes for `wp_enqueue_script`.

So here is your fixed function.

```
function load_css_js() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/gdgt-base.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'gdgt-icon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/css/gdgt.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_register_script( 'gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gdgt-base.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gdgt-base' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_js' );
```

For more information, read documentation for each function on codex.

Comment: **EDIT:** It looks like it is loading the JS file, but the code on the JS file doesn't work. (It works if I deregister the default jQuery). | Unfortunately, the fixed code isn't working :(

Comment: I just tested it, and it's working fine. I think in your theme some other function is overriding the output. Search for other `wp_enqueue_scripts` functions...

Comment: I've edited the comment. Please read that :)

Comment: That's totally different topic why your code in JS files are not working. The main reason for JS code not working with core `jQuery` but working with external `jQuery` could be that the core `jQuery` runs under noconflict mode. And your JS code is not. You will need to change your JS code for jQuery noconflict.

Comment: The thing is, I'm loading the latest jQuery from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js and it works. So what may cause the conflict?

Comment: Here is solution to your other problem. [Why $ for jquery doesn't work?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55230/why-for-jquery-doesnt-work/55232#55232). Convert your code for jQuery noconflict mode and it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much, Robert! If anyone else come across this, just use: `(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
     //your code
    });
})(jQuery);` :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Erm I've another question, I replaced `false` with `true` for `$in_footer` but it isn't working. I looked into codex as well and it looks like there is `true` on one of their examples. But it it isn't working for some reason for me.

Comment: Usually that should work, not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: Looks like you're using the same handle to register a script and style sheet. Not sure if this is a problem or not as one is CSS and the other js `gdgt-base'`

Comment: You can always just get in the habit of typing `jQuery` instead of `$` all of the time, and then you never have this issue at all. You also don't need hacks or additional closures to solve a nonexistent problem that way.

Answer (score 8):

For other idiots like myself, I thought I contribute here. :-)

I just spent an hour because I had written `array( '' )` instead of `array()` in the dependencies.

Just know, that there's a difference between:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'footerScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/appFooter.js', array( '' ), false, true );
```

and

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'footerScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/appFooter.js', array(), false, true );
```

... The first one will never load. The second one will. :-)

@Robert_Hue's answer led me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When registering and enqueueing scripts, you don’t need to call wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script(). Just call wp_enqueue_script().
Basic syntax of wp_enque_script is :

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

Now as per your code, it should be like this :

```
function load_css_js() {
            wp_enqueue_style('gdgt-base-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/gdgt-base.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('gdgt-icon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/css/gdgt.css');
            wp_enqueue_script('gdgt-base-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gdgt-base.js', array( 'jquery' ) , '2019' true);
        }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_js');
```

[visit] : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ 
documentation for more information.